# Does decrease elasticsearch heap size could help improve search performance?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

From 01-13, search performance has slowed down, maybe some metrics has reached a critical value, e.g the index doc count or store size.

From official document, I got

> Elasticsearch heavily relies on the filesystem cache in order to make search fast. In general, you should make sure that at least half the available memory goes to the filesystem cache so that Elasticsearch can keep hot regions of the index in physical memory.

And now the maxed used heap is 11.72GB and elasticsearch app specified 16G (`-Xms16g -Xmx16g`)
[image]

So if I changed elasticsearch heap size to 12GB(`-Xms12g -Xmx12g`), does filesystem cache could used more memory and the search performance could improve?

Comment: what is the RAM size of server?

Comment: @hamidbayat 32GB

Comment: i dont think decreasing the heap size would help the performance

Comment: Query performance will depend on nature of query, do u have query log enabled? If yes can you analyse which queries are taking time greater than a particular threshold? Performance degradation could be due to bad queries also(wildcard searches, scripting, aggregations returning near 10000 buckets), which wont improve much by changing any memory limit.

Comment: @PankhuriAgarwal actually the same search query and the doc count basically no big changes,  so I just feel strange. And 01-13 did a pressure test, generated many search, but the test was finished why still not  recovered?